# Docker Windows Server Core Container immediately stops after start and disappears

Tags: windows, docker, containers, docker-image

I am trying to run a docker container with the [`mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore) image but the container immediately stops and sometimes disappears.

My system:

- Windows 10 Pro 1809
- Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
- Hyper-V is enabled and Docker is configured to use Windows containers

Steps to reproduce:

1. `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803`
2. `docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803`
3. `docker ps -a`

The newly created container is shown as exited in the list:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                       COMMAND                    CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
75283da7c6fa        mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803   "c:\\windows\\system32…"   8 seconds ago       Exited (0) 5 seconds ago                        infallible_goldwasser
```

If I use the option `restart=alaways` in step 2, the container continuously restarts.
If I use the option `-it` in step 2, the container is up as long as I am in the interactive mode. As soon as I quit the interactive mode, the container stops.

Sometimes the container completely disappeares after it stops. But I cannot reproduce it right now.

Does anybody have this issue too? Does anybody know the reason for this behaviour? Does anybody know how to solve it?

**EDIT:**

Little change to title because it was wrong.